# Word, Excel web add-in prompts save dialog

Tags: ms-word, word-addins

Just wondering if I am experiencing an expected behavior - when I open my MS Word Web add-in and I want to close the document it prompts me if I want to save changes even I haven't changed anything on purpose. Let me know if there is a way not to pop up that dialog.

Thanks,

AU

Comment: This is not a programming question. Questions on general Word usage are off-topic for Stack Overflow and should be asked on an appropriate end-user forum (e.g., MS Answers). That said, if any fields in the document update (e.g. a DATE field), the document *has* changed.

Comment: oh, ok. Thanks. Will do so